# Histogram and case-insensitve python?

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram

I am currently in an intro to programming course where we are using python. We are allowed to have outside help, so me posting this is fine.

So here's the program I am suppose to write:

> Using a Python dictionary write a program that does the following:
>
> 1. Asks the user to input a paragraph of text.
> 2. Displays the frequency with which every letter of the alphabet appears in the text.
> 3. Your program should be case-insensitive, i.e. `'a'` and `'A'` should count as the same letter.
> 4. Display all the letters of the alphabet, including ones that have frequency of 0.

Here's what I have got so far:

```
def histogram(L): 
 d = {} 
 for x in L: 
   if x in d:
     d[x] += 1 
   else: d[x] = 1 
 return d 
print histogram("banana")
```

Now the problem with mine is that it only displays the letters that are in the word and is case sensitive. I really need help with the case insensitive part though. I've googled it for hours and cannot find a solution that fits my problem.

So, if you have an suggestions or if you could show me an example for me, I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Two tips: 1. `string.ascii_lowercase` has all the letters in (once you `import string`); and 2. `"A".lower() == "a"`. However, SO is *not* a place to request "write an example program for me".

Comment: @jonrsharpe and yet there are three examples within 5 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your dictionary with zeros for all lowercase letters.  Only then you should start to update it with the characters (lowercased) that you find in the paragraph.

```
import string

def histogram(paragraph):
    histogram = {}
    for char in string.lowercase:
        histogram[char] = 0
    for char in paragraph:
        if char.lower() in string.lowercase:
            histogram[char.lower()] += 1
    return histogram
```

This is a test. Check that 't' is counted 4 times, including the first 'T':

```
In [6]: paragraph = """
   ...: This is a paragraph. It goes over some lines. And
   ...: there are newlines in between!
   ...: """

In [15]: histogram(paragraph)
Out[15]:
{'a': 6,
 'b': 1,
 'c': 0,
 'd': 1,
 'e': 12,
 # ...
 't': 4,
 # ...
 'y': 0,
 'z': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

(1) @jonrsharpe makes the good point that `"StrInG".lower() == "string"`

(2) `string.ascii_letters` contains all lowercase and capital letters in a string

(3) `set(iterable)` returns the unique elements of the iterable stored in a set; furthermore, strings are iterable

(4) `dict().fromkeys(iterable, 0)` creates a dictionary with each item in `iterable` stored as a key with value 0.

This should get you pretty far along.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def histogram(L): 
    d = {} 
    for x in string.ascii_lowercase:
        d[x] = 0
    for x in L:
        if x in string.ascii_letters:
            x = x.lower()
            if x in d:
                d[x] += 1 
            else: d[x] = 1 
        else:
            continue
    return d 
print histogram("HeLlo WOrld!!")
```

Comment: @d_rez90: review the 4th point: display all letters, even those that have zero frequency.  Or am I missing something? :)

Comment: @logc you're right :) upvoted, and updated my answer.  Also upvoted yours for reading the directions correctly the first time hehe.

Answer (score 0):

```
def histogram(L): 
 #do all the letters
 d = {z:0 for z in map(lambda x: chr(ord("a") + x), xrange(26))}
 for x in L:
   x = x.lower()
   try:
     d[x] += 1 
   except KeyError:
     print("bad char")
 return d 
print histogram("banana")
```